# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm

Tags: java, jersey, jwt

i have the following code that tries to create a jwt token. there will always be an error as shown below whenever it tries to execute SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

I have manually deleted the jwt jar file and update maven again to reinstall the jar but the issue still persist.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
//Sample method to construct a JWT
public static String createJWT(String id, String issuer, String subject, 
        String payload, String role, String name, long ttlMillis) {
    String jwt = "";

    try {
        //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

        long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date now = new Date(nowMillis);

        //We will sign our JWT with our ApiKey secret
        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(apiKey.getSecret());
        Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());

        //Let's set the JWT Claims
        JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
                                    .setIssuedAt(now)
                                    .setSubject("test")
                                    .claim("role", role)
                                    .claim("name", name)
                                    .setIssuer("tester")
                                    .signWith(io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, signingKey);
                                    //.signWith(signatureAlgorithm, apiKey.getSecret().getBytes("UTF-8"));
                                    //

        //if it has been specified, let's add the expiration
        if (ttlMillis >= 0) {
        long expMillis = nowMillis + ttlMillis;
            Date exp = new Date(expMillis);
            builder.setExpiration(exp);
        }

        //Builds the JWT and serializes it to a compact, URL-safe string
        jwt = builder.compact();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return jwt;
}
```

**Error Log**

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm
    at com.test.service.JWTToken.createJWT(JWTToken.java:21)
    at com.test.controller.AccountController.authenticateUser(AccountController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter$1.run(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter.getResource(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.SubResourceLocatorRouter.apply(SubResourceLocatorRouter.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**POM Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
             <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.42</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is a run time issue. Try adding the `jar` entry in your `manifest` file, this should help you fixing your problem.

Comment: @pothios Hello, I just got same problem. Can you share what did you added to the manifest file?

Answer (score 5):

I have solved that issue on gradle by using

```
implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.0"
implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.0", {exclude group:'io.jsonwebtoken', module:'jjwt-api'}
implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.0", {exclude group:'io.jsonwebtoken', module:'jjwt-api'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add please this into your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please explain what this dependency do and how it will helps to solve the issue from the question.